# Convert File Excel to CSV on Sharepoint List Online

Tags: excel, csv, sharepoint

Dear stackoverflow members, have you ever done an Excel file conversion to CSV in Sharepoint list?

what I want is that when there is additional data or data growing, the excel file will convert to CSV automatically by scheduling.

maybe someone has a reference link. Thank you very much

Comment: 1. Where is your excel file, in a document library?
2. When do you want to convert it?
3. Why do you need a csv, maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: my excel file in folder list / document library. when I convert setting job/schedule .. just need to csv because I'll store this csv to azure data lake ..